# Network error Razão: Network unavailable java.net.SocketTimeoutException:connect timed out in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

i install dbeaver but when i try connect with my database i receive a error message
"Network error  Razão:  Network unavailable java.net.SocketTimeoutException:connect timed out"

i have proxy, i think its configured already.

i use ubuntu 22.04 kde

i tryed copy the file "cacerts" and paste in a local /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
but not works

sorry for my bad english